# ASP.net postbackurl to same page outside VS project vs. within

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, post, visual-studio-2013

I have been able to post back to the same page within my script successfully...  However, when I created a Web application project in Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web and run the SAME SCRIPT, the postback doesn't work...  the page just refreshes...  Also, instead of before the url was "Webform1.aspx" now it just shows "Webform" like this:

```
http://localhost:49201/WebForm1
```

Within the project, the form tag looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="WebForm1" id="form1">
```

vs outside it looks like this:

```
http://localhost:49621/WebForm1.aspx
```

and the form tag looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="Webform1.aspx" id="form1">
```

Is there something weird about file extensions I need to configure to postback to the same page?

Edit:

When I run my program from OUTSIDE of a VS project, it posts perfectly.

When I add my program to a Web Application project within VS, the post doesn't work, the page just refreshes...

Code below:

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CommandName="submit" PostBackUrl="~/WebForm1.aspx" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: Please, make your question more clear, and trim unneeded code

Comment: Post has been edited.  Thanks.

Comment: One question I have is why in the Visual Studio project does the url "strip" the aspx off but when it's ran outside of the project it doesn't???

Answer (score 0):

After about 7 hours of searching...  Here's what I did to fix the issue:

Create a brand new project in VS
Select Framework 4 (versus 4.5 or 4.5.1)
Add New Item from Project menu (Web Form)
Paste code, update web.config

The script now posts, which makes no sense, but it works.  Hope this helps someone not waste a day of their life.